# ActiveRecord#execute vs PG#send_query memory usage for large result sets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, memory-management

#### Background

I noticed our worker boxes spike in memory utilization whenever we hit ActiveRecord's #execute() for a large result set (>1M rows of data), however the memory stays relatively flat when I connect to PG using a raw connection and use the #send_query method instead. Additionally, the memory stays at the same high level even after #execute has finished running, which makes it seem like whatever temporary object(s) have been created are sticking around, and not getting garbage collected.

I'm not setting the result of the #execute or #send_query method to any variable in either case; it is simply being invoked to execute the SQL passed in.

#### Questions

1. Is #execute temporarily storing the result set in the PG::Result object, while send_query just streams the data without storing temporarily?
2. Why doesn't memory utilization return to normal levels after the SQL has been executed using the #execute method? Am I responsible for manually dumping any objects created in memory? Shouldn't GC take care of this?

I did some digging with ObjectSpace but couldn't pinpoint where the memory bloat was. Any help would be greatly appreciated!